# Multiprocessing runtime error freeze_support() in Mac 64 bit

Tags: macos, python-multiprocessing, python-3.8

I am trying to learn Threading and Multiprocessing on a MacOS. I am unable to launch the processes though, with python giving the following error message.

**Error**

RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

**my code:**
**parallel_processing.py**

```
import multiprocessing
import time

start= time.perf_counter()

def do_something():
    print('sleeping 1 sec....')
    time.sleep(1)
    return('done sleeping...')

# do_something()
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = do_something)

p1.start()
p2.start()

finish= time.perf_counter()

print(f'finished in {finish-start} seconds')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can resolve the issue by putting your code inside the block `if __name__ == '__main__'`. For example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def do_something():
...
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = mp.Process(target=do_something)
  p2 = mp.Process(target=do_something)

  p1.start()
  p2.start()
  ...
```

I'm not sure this is resulted from the recent macOS update or python, but it seems to have to do with how OS creates new threads, i.e. *forking* versus *spwaning*. Please see [this blog post](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/) for details.